# Surface area of a cylinder

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

Evaluating

```
expr = {Sin[t], Cos[t], Sin[p]};
ParametricPlot3D[expr, {t, 0, 2 π}, {p, 0, 2 π}]
Area[expr, {t, 0, 2 π}, {p, 0, 2 π}]
```

gives an area of `8 π`.

My question is how to interpret that area? This seems odd to me as the area is double what it should be.

Comment: Yes, let's say they are the correct limits.

Comment: I am not sure how to see the area from Plot[Sin[p],{p,0,2 Pi}]

Comment: From the ParametricPlot3D, the circumference is 2 Pi and the height is 2. So I calculated the area of the cylinder as (2 Pi)*2 = 4 Pi. Am I wrong in my approach? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the alleged problem stems from a misunderstanding of the chosen parametrization.

Answer (score 6):

Let mi visualize this mistake. Instead of constant radius we will use radius that depends of `p`:

```
expr = {1 + .1 p, 1 + .1 p, 1} { Sin[t], Cos[t], Sin[p]};

ParametricPlot3D[expr, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

As you can see, for `p` limits: `{0, 2Pi}` you are plotting your surface twice. Try with `Cos[p]` and `p` in `{0,Pi}` or whatever monotonic function for given interval.

Answer (score 5):

This is documented behavior.  The parametric forms of `ArcLength`, `Area`, and `Volume` take the parametrization as fundamental, and compute the area including multiple coverings.  The region forms of the functions take the image as fundamental, and compute the area of the embedding into `R^n`.  If you want the latter, you should use `ParametricRegion`.

From the reference page:

The parametric form of `Area` computes the area of possibly multiple coverings:

```
Area[{Cos[φ] Sin[θ], Sin[φ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 4  π}]
```

> ```
> 8 π
> ```

The region version computes the area of the image:

```
Area[ParametricRegion[{Cos[φ] Sin[θ], Sin[φ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {{θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 4 π}}]]
```

> ```
> 4 π
> ```

```
Area[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]
```

> ```
> 4 π
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should step back and think carefully about the expression you're using. Why are you using `Sin[p]` to represent the height? Also, if the height is 2, then it is not 2π.

```
expr = {Sin[t], Cos[t], p};
ParametricPlot3D[
 expr,
 {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 18, "Label", Blue] & /@ {"x", "y", "p"})
]
Area[expr, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 }]
```

[image]